# GS026 error when executing Gnosis Safe transaction and GS013

Tags: gnosis-safe

Thats for Gs026 https://etherscan.io/tx/0x987fa00b7eac473e6b97731b48c48c6d695ee3655d5475c6f2c9f08719a228ec

Trying to execute swap transaction through Curve app in gnosis safe UI , signing with safe UI and executed the tx again with safe UI for confirmation . Txs get reverted

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/bipbip/project/simulator/36f7b03f-c227-479e-ae05-380c4aaa8d13

require(currentOwner > lastOwner && owners[currentOwner] != address(0) && currentOwner != SENTINEL_OWNERS, "GS026");
execution reverted
lastOwner = currentOwner;

Thats for GS013 https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5b11d93695a43c0449700124921ed2679bd71f78403d399a028cffe1640396c5
Here again trying to swap eth for steth in curve but put manually gas gwei

assert msg.value == dx
execution reverted

require(success || safeTxGas != 0 || gasPrice != 0, "GS013");
execution reverted

Thanks in advance

Comment: GS013 means the transaction reverted in curve contract.

Comment: Most likely the reason is that the price shifted between submission and the execution date, for the exact reason it's better to check with the Curve team

Comment: They answered me that 
If it's an eth-steth transaction you need to make sure you're passing the correct value of eth with your call. 

what does it mean cause dont understand coding and just regular user through UI.

Comment: it must be the same thing I said: "the price shifted between submission and the execution date". When you're doing DEX stuff it's better to execute it quickly